# Android Message.getData().getParcelable() doesn't create new object

Tags: android, parcelable

I always thought that when I am passing custom `parcelable` object, by calling `getParcelable()`, it will return a totally new object. This is true when I am passing a parcelable object from one `Activity` to another `Activity` by putting that parcelable in the `Bundle` (`Bundle` is put in `Intent`).

But when I am trying to pass a parcelable object from a `Activity` to a background thread which has a `Handler` attach to, I don't get a new object which means if I modify the value of that object in the background thread, it will affect the object in `Activity` as well. How come? What have I done wrong?

This time the object is put in `Bundle` but the `Bundle` is put in `Message`, this is the only difference I can find when compare this to passing `Parcelable` between `Activity`.

```
//simple code sample, overwrite handleMessage() of Handler
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    SkCounter sc = msg.getData().getParcelable("abc");
    sc.testing = 99999; //if I change this value here, the object's value from Activity will change too. getParcelable() should create totally new object and changing value of it shouldn't affect other object, right? But how come this happens?
}
```

Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When passing a `Bundle` object from `Activity` to another `Activity`, Android framework will parcel and unparcel your object, the unparcel process will create a new object;

When passing a `Bundle` object through `Message`, `Message.setData()` just set the object, without doing parcel, so you are accessing the same object.

you can check `Bundle` source, your data is stored either in a `Map` or `Parcel`:

```
// Invariant - exactly one of mMap / mParcelledData will be null
// (except inside a call to unparcel)

/* package */ Map<String, Object> mMap = null;

/*
 * If mParcelledData is non-null, then mMap will be null and the
 * data are stored as a Parcel containing a Bundle.  When the data
 * are unparcelled, mParcelledData willbe set to null.
 */
/* package */ Parcel mParcelledData = null;
```

the `Bundle.unparcel()` method recreates your objects from `Parcel`.

Comment: Hi, normally how can I know that the using of bundle whether involve parcel/unparce or not? Any technique to spot it?

Comment: `msg.setData((Bundle)bundle.clone());` This doesn't work :( Why?

Comment: @GMsoF I think you shouldn't rely on parcel to recreate your object, if you need a new object, create it and pass it.

Comment: @GMsoF Yes clone doesn't work. I modified answer. You should create a new object yourself.

Comment: OK I got it. Do you know how to determine a bundle will be parcel/unparcel or not when the bundle is pass from one context to another?